# Revit Python have problem with isinstance()

Tags: python, revit-api

I use  if isinstance(ins,list): to check . but it returned false Although ins is the List[Object]

```
def getname(ins):
    name=[]
    if isinstance(ins,list):
        for i in ins:
            name.append(i.Name)
    else:
        name.append(ins.Name)
    return name

Levels = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Level).ToElements()
ULevels = UnwrapElement(Levels)
Levelsname = getname(ULevels)
```

Error message is:

> AttributeError: 'List[object]' object has no attribute 'Name'

Comment: The simple explanation is that `ULevels.Name` does not exist.  Why did you expect it to?

Comment: Levels and ULevels are returning the list[object] (some case can be object)  , these object can get name property. my problem here is isinstance( Ulevels, list) return "false" value. I expect it should be "true" to make Ulevels go to for..i loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line of code like this:

```
[UnwrapElement(x).Name for x in FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Level).ToElements()]
```

Since I can see you are using Dynamo you can also do it like this:

[image]

Comment: But do you know what happened with my problem?

Comment: sure. your check for `isinstance(ins, list)` checks the `ins` object if it is a Python list, and that returns `False` since it's a .NET type List<object>. It then proceeds to call `ins.Name` and you get that error. So the issue you see is because `UnwrapElement()` method returns a .NET typed list. Try not to mix .NET objects with Python objects to avoid this.